Routing mobile hotspot traffic through home VPN
I have a mobile hotspot (M3000 Inseego Hotspot). I can connect to it just fine and get internet through T-Mobile. I also know how to use my laptop to connect to my home VPN when I'm on the hotspot connection.
Is there any way to set up my hotspot such that any device that connects to my hotspot is routed through my home VPN network?

Ensure that your laptop is configured to connect to your home VPN when you're on the hotspot connection. Check the settings of your M3000 Inseego Hotspot to see if there's an option to enable VPN passthrough. This option allows VPN traffic from connected devices to pass through the hotspot to your home VPN network. If such an option is available, enable it. Once VPN passthrough is enabled, any device that connects to your hotspot should be able to access the internet through your home VPN network. Check the settings of your M3000 Inseego Hotspot to see if there's an option to enable VPN passthrough. This option allows VPN traffic from connected devices to pass through the hotspot to your home VPN network. If such an option is available, enable it.
Once VPN passthrough is enabled, any device that connects to your hotspot should be able to access the internet through your home VPN network.
You can check this for here nseego M3000 User Manual
